# Difficult to scan barcode using zxing android

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing in my android app to scan a barcode but it seems to be a little bit difficult process as first I need to rotate the camera and also autofocus is not working properly as difficult to scan a code.
Here is my code:

```
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(Arrays.asList("QR_CODE", "CODE_128"));
        integrator.setCameraId(0);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
        integrator.setTimeout(60000);
        integrator.setPrompt("");
        integrator.initiateScan();
```

Any thought how I can scan a bar code in any angle and how the library start autofocus the bar code image automatically?

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/86 and go through this https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: you can add `com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity` in your manifest file and check.